# Label style for equations

Tags: equations

I want label equation as 1.1,  1.2.  etc
However, what I got is -1.2, -1.3.  etc.

Is there any parameter control this style? The file for example like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno, screen]{amsart}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,pdfstartview=FitH, pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{test}
\maketitle
\begin{equation}\label{eq3.3}
\gamma(x)\le \gamma(y).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I just noticed the difference between my code and the answer below. I am using an envirment with out 'section', so that is why the TeX generated the symbol -1.1. Adding section solves the problem.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the information you've provided, while interesting, doesn't allow us to experiment.  please complete this file by adding an example between `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that shows the problem when compiled.

Comment: So you mean that it currently displays
`E=mc² (-1.2)`
instead of
`E=mc² (1.2)`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your code snippet does *not* give rise, by itself, to the unwanted behavior you describe, viz., the extra `-` symbols ahead of the equation numbers. Please create a compilable example that generates the unwanted behavior.

Comment: @MWijnand, yes, exactly

Comment: Hi. Your updated code still doesn't generate the problem behavior you've described, at least not when compiled with pdfLaTeX from the TeXlive2015 distribution.

Comment: @user60933: Which compiler did you use?

Comment: I am using TeXShop 3.58 on OSX 10.11.1

Comment: TeXshop is a front-end to MacTeX. Which version of MakTeX is installed on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce OP's problem.  This works fine for me:  (copied redundant headers from original)

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno, screen]{amsart}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,pdfstartview=FitH, pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
\title{test}
\maketitle

\section{Hmm}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3.3}
\gamma(x)\le \gamma(y).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to indicate more clearly that your posting isn't so much a solution to the problem the OP claims having as a demonstration that the OP's code doesn't actually generate the problem in the first place.